# Spring boot restricting some keywords in route url

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have used "services" and "settings" keyword in my route url.

But, Spring boot is restricting it.

When trying to hit the url then it shows "site taking too long to respond".

**But, when I change the keywords from some else then it work well.**

Example: http://localhost:4125/api/v1/settings/pg/get/{id} - Not Working

When Changed: http://localhost:4125/api/v1/Mysettings/pg/get/{id} - Working

Example: http://localhost:4125/api/v1/services/pg/get/{id} - Not Working

When Changed: http://localhost:4125/api/v1/Myservices/pg/get/{id} - Working

If anybody can help me with this then please do help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide some code snippets

Comment: @MatthewS. I have edited the question so that reader can have complete information about the issues I am facing. Request you to kindly re-read the question again, please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`services` or `settings` is not a reserved word.
Most likely this seems to be an issue with resolver mapper.
Can you double check if you don't have multiple resources with same resource path and also check your application logs while you make a request.